# Earthling/s equivalent for Mars and Venus

Tags: nouns

> The first earthling in space was a dog.

What about Mars or Venus.

marsling? venusling?

I am looking for a word for an inhabitant of Mars (and another word for the inhabitant of Venus) that "feels" the same as **earthling**.

**Martian** seems to me more like the equivalent of **human/man** than an general living organism living on the planet Mars. For example, most people don't imagine a bacteria from Mars when you say "Martian". They imagine homanoid-like creature from the planet Mars. That is why I see the word martian as an equivalent of human or man and not an equivalent of earthling.

Any idea?

Comment: Since your comment to oerkelens’ answer has made it clear that you’re not just looking for a term for an inhabitant of Mars and Venus, I think you’re basically out of luck, unless you don’t mind creating your own neologisms. _Marsling_ and _Venusling_ both work fine for me (they’re transparent and clear), though they’re a bit odd. _Martite_ and _Venerite_ might work as well, but I’m not sure they ‘feel’ the same as _earthling_ to you.

Comment: Marsling is OK? To me it sounds great, however, I am Czech, so, I have no idea how it sounds to native English speakers.

Comment: For the record, _earthling_ is also quite unambiguously humanoid. A bacterium from Earth would never be described as an earthling, either. If we’re talking about a life form that is very different to humans, for example bacterium-like, _Martian_ would be much better than _Marsling_ (which would definitely sound like a humanoid type of Martian).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martianism, Venusianism?

If no word exists you are free to create your own. It's your human birthright. Every earthanism is allowed to do that.

Just mash Mars and organism together -- Marsianism.
Just mash Venus and organism together -- Venusianism.
Just mash Jupiter and organism together -- Jupiterism
Just mash Syllogy and organism together -- Syllogism  (just kidding)

Comment: Capital + organism = Capitalism ? ;D

Comment: yeah social + animal + organism = socianimalism

Answer (score 7):

That would be a [Martian](https://www.google.com/search?q=Martian) or a [Venusian](https://www.google.com/search?q=Venusian).

Comment: I know, but it is not very poetic when you compare that to earthling ;(

Comment: You could try Venerian, but it seems to have different connotations...

Comment: Martian is to me more like the word human/man. E.g. by martian you often means an intelligent humanoid-like being from Mars and not a bacteria or a rat :D from Mars even though the bacteria is technically a Martian too.

Comment: The OED does not have any quotes at all for _Venerean_ in the sense of ‘associated with the planet Venus’. All the senses and quotes are related to the goddess, not the planet.

Comment: The "different connotations" are for *venereal,* surely? (Which is also connected to the goddess of love, Venus)

Answer (score 1):

Creatures and critters from Mars, Venus, and Earth are respectively called Martians, Venusians, and Earthlings (or [Terrans](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/terran)) because those names are associated with such planets.

And so, the opposite of "human" is not "Martian," "Venusian," or "Plutonian," but "nonhuman."

> ["The difference between them and you" he had said, "is the difference between a Terran dog and a human."](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=IMaaLXjuup8C&pg=PT68&lpg=PT68&dq=%22a+terran+dog%22&source=bl&ots=P66XDsm5xQ&sig=k-Sdt_3vha-KSN0KUzUxxQDAl5E&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=1HdOU-izIamV0AXAu4GICQ&ved=0CF8Q6AEwDQ#v=onepage&q=%22a%20terran%20dog%22&f=false)
>
> [He owns a Martian dog, K-9, and Martian slaves.](http://looneytunesshow.wikia.com/wiki/Marvin_the_Martian)
>
> [Could Martian bacteria have seeded Earth?](http://science.time.com/2012/10/11/could-martian-bacteria-have-seeded-earth/)

Comment: Could you please edit this into a more coherent answer? This reads more like a series of notes or comments than an answer to the question.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Does it sound or look any better to you, Bradd?

Comment: A bit, although it's not clear what makes this answer stand out from the others, and the list of quotes seems more random than authoritative. I'm not sure what's the point of it; perhaps make that explicit?

Comment: @BraddSzonye The fact that "Terran" is another name for "Earthling" makes it sort of more obvious that "Martian" and "Venusian" are associated with the planets, in the same way as "Earthling" is.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd be surprised to see *Terran* outside of a sci fi story. We more often use *Terrestrial* for Earth-based life, or Earthling for people specifically.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Sure. But terrestrial is the opposite of what is extraterrestrial spacewise.

Comment: @BraddSzonye The thing is the OP claims that terms like "Martian" and "Venusian" are not (or doesn't sound) analogous with "Earrhling." By pointing up "Terran" as a synonym for "Earthling," I just wanted to demonstrate those actually are.